# std::vector<uint8_t> manually copying instead of calling memcpy when C++11/14 enabled

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, c++14, stdvector

Using gcc 4.9, cross-compiling for ARM using the Linaro toolchain, I have found the compiled result of `vector.assign()` changes when adding `-std=c++14`, in a way that creates significant performance problems.

I have tried several different ways of doing this allocation + copy, but all of them have this performance problem as long as I'm using `std::vector` to do it.

I can reproduce the problem with this toy example:

**VectorTest.h**

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <vector>

struct VectorWrapper_t
{
    VectorWrapper_t(uint8_t const* pData, size_t length);
    std::vector<uint8_t> data;
};
```

**VectorTest.cpp**

```
#include "VectorTest.h"

VectorWrapper_t::VectorWrapper_t(uint8_t const* pData, size_t length)
{
    data.assign(pData, pData + length);
}
```

gcc flags:

```
-std=c++14 \
-mthumb -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a9 \
-mlittle-endian -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon -Wa,-mimplicit-it=thumb \
-O2 -g
```

Viewing the assembly, I can see why: the original version (C++03, I'm assuming?) calls `memmove`, whereas the C++14 version instead adds an extra loop that it looks like is copying the data manually. Looking at the `.loc` tags gcc adds with `-fverbose-asm`, the instructions in this loop come from `stl_construct.h` and `stl_uninitialized.h`.

Changing to gcc 5.2.1 (with C++14), it compiles nearly identically to the C++03 example, except with `memcpy` instead of `memmove`.

I'm able to get around this problem by using `std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]>` instead of a `vector` here. However, I would like to get to the bottom of this issue to figure out if other places using `vector`s could have performance problems and how to potentially fix them (updating to gcc 5.2 isn't practical).

So my question is: **Why does it compile differently under C++11/14?**

For reference, `gcc --version` reports:
`arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc (Linaro GCC 4.9-2014.12) 4.9.3 20141205 (prerelease)`.

Here is the assembly gcc generated:

```
# C++03, gcc 4.9

    push    {r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}    @
    movs    r3, #0  @ tmp118,
    mov r4, r0  @ this, this
    str r3, [r0]    @ tmp118, MEM[(struct _Vector_impl *)this_1(D)]._M_start
    mov r5, r2  @ length, length
    str r3, [r0, #4]    @ tmp118, MEM[(struct _Vector_impl *)this_1(D)]._M_finish
    str r3, [r0, #8]    @ tmp118, MEM[(struct _Vector_impl *)this_1(D)]._M_end_of_storage
    cbnz    r2, .L19    @ length,
    mov r0, r4  @, this
    pop {r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, pc}    @
.L19:
    mov r0, r2  @, length
    mov r6, r1  @ pData, pData
    bl  _Znwj   @
    mov r2, r5  @, length
    mov r1, r6  @, pData
    mov r7, r0  @ D.13516,
    bl  memmove @
    ldr r0, [r4]    @ D.13515, MEM[(struct vector *)this_1(D)].D.11902._M_impl._M_start
    cbz r0, .L3 @ D.13515,
    bl  _ZdlPv  @
.L3:
    add r5, r5, r7  @ D.13515, D.13516
    str r7, [r4]    @ D.13516, MEM[(struct vector *)this_1(D)].D.11902._M_impl._M_start
    str r5, [r4, #4]    @ D.13515, MEM[(struct vector *)this_1(D)].D.11902._M_impl._M_finish
    mov r0, r4  @, this
    str r5, [r4, #8]    @ D.13515, MEM[(struct vector *)this_1(D)].D.11902._M_impl._M_end_of_storage
    pop {r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, pc}    @
.L6:
    ldr r0, [r4]    @ D.13515, MEM[(struct _Vector_base *)this_1(D)]._M_impl._M_start
    cbz r0, .L5 @ D.13515,
    bl  _ZdlPv  @
.L5:
    bl  __cxa_end_cleanup   @

# C++14, gcc 4.9

    push    {r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}    @
    movs    r3, #0  @ tmp157,
    mov r6, r0  @ this, this
    str r3, [r0]    @ tmp157, MEM[(struct _Vector_impl *)this_1(D)]._M_start
    mov r5, r2  @ length, length
    str r3, [r0, #4]    @ tmp157, MEM[(struct _Vector_impl *)this_1(D)]._M_finish
    str r3, [r0, #8]    @ tmp157, MEM[(struct _Vector_impl *)this_1(D)]._M_end_of_storage
    cbnz    r2, .L25    @ length,
    mov r0, r6  @, this
    pop {r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, pc}    @
.L25:
    mov r0, r2  @, length
    mov r4, r1  @ pData, pData
    bl  _Znwj   @
    adds    r3, r4, r5  @ D.20345, pData, length
    mov r7, r0  @ __result,
    cmp r4, r3  @ pData, D.20345
    ittt    ne
    addne   r1, r4, #-1 @ ivtmp.76, pData,
    movne   r3, r0  @ __result, __result
    addne   r4, r0, r5  @ D.20346, __result, length
    beq .L26    @,
.L7:
    ldrb    r2, [r1, #1]!   @ zero_extendqisi2  @ D.20348, MEM[base: _48, offset: 0]
    cbz r3, .L6 @ __result,
    strb    r2, [r3]    @ D.20348, MEM[base: __result_23, offset: 0B]
.L6:
    adds    r3, r3, #1  @ __result, __result,
    cmp r3, r4  @ __result, D.20346
    bne .L7 @,
.L8:
    ldr r0, [r6]    @ D.20346, MEM[(struct vector *)this_1(D)].D.18218._M_impl._M_start
    cbz r0, .L5 @ D.20346,
    bl  _ZdlPv  @
.L5:
    str r7, [r6]    @ __result, MEM[(struct vector *)this_1(D)].D.18218._M_impl._M_start
    mov r0, r6  @, this
    str r4, [r6, #4]    @ D.20346, MEM[(struct vector *)this_1(D)].D.18218._M_impl._M_finish
    str r4, [r6, #8]    @ D.20346, MEM[(struct vector *)this_1(D)].D.18218._M_impl._M_end_of_storage
    pop {r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, pc}    @
.L26:
    adds    r4, r0, r5  @ D.20346, __result, length
    b   .L8 @
.L11:
    ldr r0, [r6]    @ D.20346, MEM[(struct _Vector_base *)this_1(D)]._M_impl._M_start
    cbz r0, .L10    @ D.20346,
    bl  _ZdlPv  @
.L10:
    bl  __cxa_end_cleanup   @

# C++14, gcc 5.2

    push    {r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}    @
    movs    r3, #0  @ tmp118,
    mov r4, r0  @ this, this
    str r3, [r0]    @ tmp118, MEM[(struct _Vector_impl *)this_1(D)]._M_start
    str r3, [r0, #4]    @ tmp118, MEM[(struct _Vector_impl *)this_1(D)]._M_finish
    str r3, [r0, #8]    @ tmp118, MEM[(struct _Vector_impl *)this_1(D)]._M_end_of_storage
    cbnz    r2, .L19    @ length,
    mov r0, r4  @, this
    pop {r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, pc}    @
.L19:
    mov r0, r2  @, length
    mov r6, r1  @ pData, pData
    mov r5, r2  @ length, length
    bl  _Znwj   @
    mov r2, r5  @, length
    mov r1, r6  @, pData
    mov r7, r0  @ D.20824,
    bl  memcpy  @
    ldr r0, [r4]    @ D.20823, MEM[(struct vector *)this_1(D)].D.18751._M_impl._M_start
    cbz r0, .L3 @ D.20823,
    bl  _ZdlPv  @
.L3:
    add r5, r5, r7  @ D.20823, D.20824
    str r7, [r4]    @ D.20824, MEM[(struct vector *)this_1(D)].D.18751._M_impl._M_start
    str r5, [r4, #4]    @ D.20823, MEM[(struct vector *)this_1(D)].D.18751._M_impl._M_finish
    mov r0, r4  @, this
    str r5, [r4, #8]    @ D.20823, MEM[(struct vector *)this_1(D)].D.18751._M_impl._M_end_of_storage
    pop {r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, pc}    @
.L6:
    ldr r0, [r4]    @ D.20823, MEM[(struct _Vector_base *)this_1(D)]._M_impl._M_start
    cbz r0, .L5 @ D.20823,
    bl  _ZdlPv  @
.L5:
    bl  __cxa_end_cleanup   @
```

Comment: It probably won't make much of a difference, but why assign instead of initialize? The latter could avoid one allocation. `VectorWrapper_t(uint8_t const* pData, size_t length) : data(pData, pData + length) {}`

Comment: This question seems better suited to a Linaro bug report.

Comment: 2 possibilities: either the code starts the same, but gcc-5+ detects that the loop is equivalent to memcpy and replaces it with a call to memcpy, or libstdc++ gained some new special path that calls memcpy. Try passing `-fdump-tree-all` and look at some early / late dumps to determine what is going on.

Comment: @juanchopanza yes, that would be better practice. Regardless, it's one of the many things I tried that didn't fix the problem.

Comment: I don't have any of the standards at hand, but did the specification of assign change between them? If not, I'd call it a regression bug

Comment: Speaking of performance: How much slower is it?

Comment: @MikeMB - around 5-10x slower, depending on data size (typically it's a few kB, but it can get up to a couple MB)

Comment: the real question is: how compiler knew it could replace `memcpy` with `memmove`? `assign` doesn't take ownership of passed array

Comment: @AndreiR. The `move` in `memmove` isn't related to C++11 move semantics. Neither function modifies the source array.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This was a GCC bug in the 4.9.2 release, see [PR 64476](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64476). The difference between the default `-std=gnu++03` mode and `-std=c++14` is that for C++11 and later it's possible to have trivial types that aren't assignable (because they can have a deleted assignment operator) which causes the implementation of `std::uninitialized_copy` to take a different (slower) code path. The check for assignability was wrong, meaning that we took the slow path when we didn't need to.

I fixed it two years ago for GCC 4.9.3, but your compiler is based on a snapshot made between the 4.9.2 and 4.9.3 releases and is a few weeks too old to have the fix.

You could ask Linaro to update their GCC 4.9 compiler to 4.9.4, or at least to apply the patch fixing this bug.